# Middleware should fail the request after calling next delegate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I had the idea of implementing a `TransactionMiddleware` that will call the `SaveChanges` method of a EFCore context. The implementation for this `TransactionMiddleware` looks like this:

```cs
namespace DotNetCMS.Persistence.EntityFrameworkCore.AspNetCore
{
    public sealed class TransactionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public TransactionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, CmsContext cmsContext)
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
            await cmsContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And I've registered it in the `Startup.cs` file:

```cs
namespace DotNetCMS.Rest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // ...

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, CmsContext context)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseMiddleware<TransactionMiddleware>();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This works as expected, the only crucial thing that is missing is proper error handling in case the `SaveChangesAsync` call fails for some reason. I've tried to throw an exception in the `TransactionMiddleware` to simulate that, and then I had to realize that the response is already sent (so the user does not see any error message and assumes that everything has gone right) and instead the error is outputted to stdout.

Now the question is: How do I get ASP.NET to return a response with an error message instead?

I already tried to register the `TransactionMiddleware` after `UseEndpoints`, but then it is not called at all, so it seems that the `UseEndpoints` is a terminating middleware...

EDIT:

The controller action I am testing this against:

```cs
namespace DotNetCMS.Rest.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class PagesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly PageService _pageService;

        public PagesController(PageService pageService)
        {
            _pageService = pageService;
        }

        // ...
        
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<Page> PostPage(CreateCommand createCommand)
        {
            var page = _pageService.Create(createCommand);

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetPage), new { id = page.Id }, page);
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach has a few problems:

- You can't throw an exception from the last middleware in the pipeline. No code will handle it.
- You can't modify a response after it has started. To explain this in more details:

  1. Your middleware is called and it invokes the next middleware
  2. The action does it job and returns a result (regardless of status code), anything other than an exception
  3. The MVC pipeline writes the result to the response (with formatting and everything)
  4. Your middleware gets the result from the inner middleware, at which point the response has already started
  5. Your middleware, when saving changes fails, would then try to modify the response that was already written.

You have a few options, though, to achieve what you want:

1. You can use a temporary `MemoryStream` as a helper, by replacing `context.Response.Body` before calling the next middleware.
2. You can use something else than a middleware, for example, an [`IAsyncResultFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iasyncresultfilter?view=aspnetcore-5.0).